# Is it possible to do a SelectorContext on the value of a node?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The question is in the title. I would like to knw if it's possible to select only elements that have a specific value of an attribute

Comment: Please expand this question with perhaps code you've tried, what failed, etc.

Comment: Via css? `var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[attr_name="attr_value"]')` like that? This returns an object collection.